# python linear regression implementation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I've been trying to do my own implementation of a simple linear regression algorithm, but I'm having some trouble with the gradient descent.

Here's how I coded it:

```
def gradientDescentVector(data, alpha, iterations):
    a = 0.0
    b = 0.0
    X = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    m = data.shape[0]
    it = np.ones(shape=(m,2))
    for i in range(iterations):
        predictions = X.dot(a).flatten() + b

        errors_b = (predictions - y)
        errors_a = (predictions - y) * X

        a = a - alpha * (1.0 / m) * errors_a.sum()
        b = b - alpha * (1.0 / m) * errors_b.sum()
    return a, b
```

Now, I know this won't scale well with more variables, but I was just trying with the simple version first, and follow up from there.

I was following the gradient descent algorithm from the machine learning course at coursera:

[image]

But I'm getting infinite values after ~90 iterations (on a specific dataset), and haven't been able to wrap my head around this so far.

I've tried iterating over each value before I learned about numpy's broadcasting and was getting the same results.

If anyone could shed some light on what could be the problem here, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the parameters are diverging from the optimum ones. One possible reason may be that you are using too large a value for the learning rate ("alpha"). Try decreasing the learning rate. Here is a rule of thumb. Start always from a small value like 0.001. Then try increasing the learning rate by taking a three time higher learning rate than previous. If it gives less MSE error (or whatever error function you are using), then its fine. If not try taking a value between 0.001 and 0.003. Next if the latter hold true, then try this recursively until you reach a satisfying MSE.

Comment: I had already tried to 0.001 and it was not working, but I went to try again with an even lower learning rate, 0.0000001, and it started working properly, thanks for that!

Tho I wasn't using any kind of error function, maybe I'll try to look into it after.